# Powershell: Querying TS with Get-Process, SAMAccount and ComputerName?

Tags: windows, powershell, server, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to code something that would query my TS for specific applications and select the SAM Account of the user using that process and their computer name. I already have something that looks like this but I'm having a hard time integrating the query of the SAM Account and the Computer name.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName "MYSERVER" |
Where {$_.name -eq "winword.exe"} |
Invoke-WmiMethod -Name GetOwner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loose the wmiobject for the process when you pipe it directly to `Invoke-WmiMethod`. You can use `Foreach-Object` to generate an object or use a custom column with `Select-Object` like this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName "localhost" |
Where-Object {$_.name -eq "notepad.exe"} |
Select-Object CSName, ProcessName, @{n="Owner";e={$_.GetOwner().User}}

CSName   ProcessName Owner
------   ----------- -----
FRODE-PC notepad.exe frode
```

When writing scripts with custom columns, I prefer to write define them earlier so they are more readable and can be reused, like this:

```
$OwnerColumn = @{
    Name="Owner"
    Expression={ $_.GetOwner().User }
}

....
Where-Object ... |
Select-Object CSName, ProcessName, $OwnerColumn
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! I like the fact that you declare OwnerColumn outside so It's like an object! I'll definitely keep that in mind ;)! Thanks again!

Comment: It is in fact a hashtable-object. Read more abou calculated columns here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx  . Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem to close the question. :-)